# Ldap Configuration Help from Linux

Tags: linux, ldap

We had a domain migration.
Since then, users are unable to login to our Mediawiki.
It seems that the first ldap binding is failing, hence the web users are unable to authenticate and login.

This is the Log output:

```
2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering validDomain

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a User is using a valid domain (my-domain).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Setting domain as: my-domain

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getCanonicalName

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Username is: WebLoginUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering validDomain

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a User is using a valid domain (my-domain).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering Connect

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using TLS or not using encryption.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using servers:  ldap://my-domain.com:389

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a PHP's LDAP connect method returned true (note, this does not imply it connected to the server).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getUserDN

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Doing a proxy bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind as ADAdminUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Fetched username is not a string (check your hook code...). This message can be safely ignored if you do not have the SetUsernameAttributeFromLDAP hook defined.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Munged username: WebLoginUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getCanonicalName

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Username is: 172.xx.xx.xx

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering validDomain

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a User is using a valid domain (my-
domain).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering Connect

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using TLS or not using encryption.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using servers:  ldap://my-
domain.com:389

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a PHP's LDAP connect method returned true (note, this does not imply it connected to the server).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getUserDN

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Doing a proxy bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind as ADAdminUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Fetched username is not a string (check your hook code...). This message can be safely ignored if you do not have the SetUsernameAttributeFromLDAP hook defined.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Munged username: 172.xx.xx.xx

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getCanonicalName

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Username is: 172.xx.xx.xx

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering validDomain

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a User is using a valid domain (my-
domain).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering Connect

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using TLS or not using encryption.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using servers:  ldap://my-domain.com:389

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a PHP's LDAP connect method returned 
true (note, this does not imply it connected to the server).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getUserDN

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Doing a proxy bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind as ADAdminUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Fetched username is not a string (check your hook code...). This message can be safely ignored if you do not have 
the SetUsernameAttributeFromLDAP hook defined.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Munged username: 172.xx.xx.xx

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering userExists

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering authenticate for username WebLoginUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering Connect

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using TLS or not using encryption.

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Using servers:  ldap://my-
domain.com:389

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a PHP's LDAP connect method returned true (note, this does not imply it connected to the server).

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering getSearchString

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Doing a straight bind

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a userdn is: WebLoginUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Binding as the user

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Failed to bind as WebLoginUser

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering allowPasswordChange

2020-03-29 19:29:23 wiki wikidb-exa_: 2.0a Entering modifyUITemplate
```

---

This is the config:

```
require_once( "$IP/extensions/LdapAuthentication/LdapAuthentication.php" );

$wgAuth = new LdapAuthenticationPlugin();

$wgLDAPDebug = 3;

$wgLDAPDomainNames = array( 'my-domain');

$wgLDAPServerNames = array( 'my-domain' => 'my-domain.com',);

$wgLDAPSearchStrings = array('my-domain' => 'USER-NAME',);

$wgLDAPEncryptionType = array( 'my-domain' => 'clear',);

$wgLDAPBaseDNs = array( 'my-domain' => 'CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com');

$wgLDAPSearchAttributes = array( 'my-domain' => 'sAMAccountName');

$wgLDAPProxyAgent =  array( 'my-domain' => "ADAdminUser");

$wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword = array( 'my-domain' => "********");

$wgLDAPUpdateLDAP = array('my-domain'=>false);

$wgLDAPAddLDAPUsers = array('my-domain'=>false);

$wgLDAPPreferences = array( 'my-domain' => true );
$wgDebugLogGroups["ldap"] = "/tmp/debug_ldap.log";
```

---

Testing LDAP connection and query with this command, returned the expected result:

```
ldapsearch -x -D "CN=ADAdminUser,CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com" -W -h my-domain.com -b "CN=saWebLoginUserarn,CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com"
```

What in my configuration is wrong?

Comment: Try `$wgLDAPProxyAgent = array( 'my-domain' => "CN=ADAdminUser,CN=Users,DC=my-domain,DC=com");`. Also `$wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword` appears twice so the second one overrides the first one, refer to ldapsearch's -W argument.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've removed the second wgLDAPProxyAgentPassword = array( 'my-domain' => ""); line, changed the $wgLDAPProxyAgent as you recommended but still it is failing on the binding of ADAdminUser to the ldap and then for the webLoginUser with same error as in the above log.